# UI automation, appleScript Keyboard shortcuts for non-menued items Preview?

Tags: applescript, ui-automation

I am trying to create a keyboard shortcut action for Preview, namely Draw and Sketch. However, they are are the NON-menued items, which means can't get it done in System Preference  I see someone done it  from [inspiration](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119285/keyboard-shortcuts-for-non-menued-items-itunes-11), it is possible, but when I try to follow alone, here is my code so far and please help me complete this. here are the action. [image]

Here is the error I am facing now[image]

after some researches, does the  UI/accessibility inspector [image: UI inspector] help?

```
activate application "Preview"
        delay 0.4
    set the menuItem to "Draw"
    tell application "System Events"
        try
            tell application process "Preview" to click radio button menuItem of radio group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
        on error
            try
                tell application process "Preview" to click radio button menuItem of radio group 1 of window 1
            on error errorM

                display dialog errorM

            end try
        end try
    end tell
```

ideally, trying to make it to work when all bars are hidden, 
but if not possible. can we make it to work vwith mark up bar is shown. as below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This work for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave

```
tell application "Preview" to activate
repeat while application "Preview" is not running
    delay 0.2
end repeat
tell application "System Events"
    try
        click menu item "Show Markup Toolbar" of menu 1 of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1 of application process "Preview"
    end try
    delay 0.5
    try
        click menu item "Show Toolbar" of menu 1 of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1 of application process "Preview"
    end try
    delay 0.5
    repeat while not (exists of toolbar 1 of window 1 of application process "Preview")
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
    set description2 to a reference to every checkbox of toolbar 1 of window 1 of application process "Preview"
    set theCheckboxes to description of description2

    if item 1 of theCheckboxes is "Draw" then
        set checkBoxDraw to 1
    else
        set checkBoxDraw to 2
    end if
    if item 1 of theCheckboxes is "Sketch" then
        set checkBoxSketch to 1
    else
        set checkBoxSketch to 2
    end if
    delay 1
    -- Below, insert either  checkBoxSketch for "Sketch" or checkBoxDraw for "Draw" 
    click checkbox checkBoxDraw of toolbar 1 of window 1 of application process "Preview"
end tell
-- without these next following lines, the toolbar  "Draw" or "Sketch" do not appear to be selected
tell application "Preview" to tell window 1
    set visible to false
    set visible to true
end tell
delay 3
```

Comment: How should we locate the UI element systematically ?  Is there a way to list all UI element of an application?

Comment: can you please try again when the layout that posted, I forgot the default layout, otherwise, will try it myself.  or you can post the layout that work for you, will run again after matching the working layout.

Comment: @ch1zpink, Thank you for updating the code.  Maybe I am doing it wrong from Automator from the beginning.  You code run without error but still don't accomplish the task, choosing the Draw as the current tool.

Comment: Posted a completely new version.. Try running that in script editor app.... Curious to see if you will still get errors